# Why isn’t my transmission working after replacing the engine

Tags: transmission

I just replaced the engine on my 2014 Hyundai Sonata and now the transmission won’t get into any gear at all.

I know for sure the transmission was good before the engine blew.

Comment: The lever won't move, or the vehicle doesn't move in any gear?  Did you forget the torque converter?

Comment: Clutch plate in backwards?